# Is there a way to stop a long running task running on a worker node?

Tags: node.js, cluster-computing

I wish to abort a long running task running on a nodeJS cluster worker node.The approach I am using is to fetch the pid of the worker node and kill it using SIGKILL. It kills the nodeJS worker but the task starts to run on another cluster node.

Is there a good way to stop a running task on a worker node provided I am using Bull as a task queue.

Comment: Have you tried process.exit('code') on the cluster?

Comment: Event loop of that process is not free
It requires another free node to kill the process

Comment: It seems like the problem is with your task queue as it doesn't sound like this is a regular nodejs cluster.  I think we'd need the code for how you're using the task queue and see exactly what libraries you are using so we can assess how to remove something from the queue before you kill the process so it can't come back to life again when you kill the worker process.  There is no information currently in your question to help us help you in that way.  We need to see code.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an idea, but you could extend that worker node with a callback listening on the SIGKILL event. This callback should remove the running task from the queue, before the process shuts down itself, so the task won't return back to the queue.

There are better solutions by using a better architecture, but this one could be a simple extension to your already working project.